# How to divide objects into limited area with C#?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, math

im currently working on a game and i need to divide a changeable amount of objects in to a limited area. I made a image to explain better:

[image]

(I know its a bit difficult to understand)
So i can't find a solution and couldn't figure it out myself. I tried a few ways to multiply and divide the object count with the index and the xMaximum but it didn't work as expected.

This is what i tried:

```
public float xMin, xMax;

private void UpdateValues()
{

    for(int i = 0; i < transform.childCount; i++)
    {
        float value = xMin;
        float maxIndex = transform.childCount;
        float index = i;

        value = transform.position.x + xMax / (maxIndex * index);

        transform.GetChild(i).transform.position = new Vector3(transform.position.x, transform.position.y, value);
    }
}
```

It just gave me the wrong numbers and i can't figure the right way out.

The available variables are:

- xMinimum, xMaximum
- objectcount
- objectindex

Comment: What specifically are you stuck on?

Comment: Well, the objects dont equally divide up in the space, or their just way over the limit. Also i want them to start from the middle and then go out to two sides, that also dosn't work

Answer (score 1):

If you want it to look exactly how you have shown it on images then it might be a little more tricky. Objects don’t fill the area always the same, so we need to add some exceptions:

- if there is only 1 item, then just set it’s position to (xMin + xMax) / 2f
- if item is first, and there are more than one, set its position to xMin + (squareWidth / 2f) (or something else if pivot is not in the middle)
- if item is last and there are more than one, set its position to xMax - (squareWidth / 2f)
- the remaining area, which is of size xMax - 2 * squareWidth need to be divided equally between all remaining objects. Compute the amount remaining objects (which will be all objects - 2 (first and last)). Divide remaining area by number of objects plus 1. Set remaining objects position in a loop, the statement inside will look something like this: `value = (i+1) * remainingArea / (transform.childCount - 2 + 1)`

That’s the rough list of steps that might help. In this example I assume, that xMin is 0, otherwise you will need to take that into account and for eg. Remaining area won’t be just xMax - 2 * squareWidth, but xMax - xMin - 2 * squareWidth.

Also you might find yourself being off a half a square here and there, but that should be easy to correct.